# random distribution on n-dimensional cube in matlab

Tags: matlab

How can i generate random-uniform points in the surface of a N-dimensional cube with edge E?

There is a code for generating for a N-dimensional sphere, but I can't figure it out how can I generate it for a cube.

Comment: What's this "code" you found?  Show us any attempts you made and the problems you're facing.

Comment: it's interesting task: how to recognize the attachment of the point to this surface... so I can offer this solution: randomly generate N-1 coordinates for this point and calculate last coordinate through the surface formula. In general it has N roots (or less). So you again randomly choose one of them.

Answer (score 1):

The nice thing with the N-dimensional hypercube is that its faces are hypercubes of dimension (N-1). Therefore I would proceed in four steps steps.

- Draw a random integer called d in the range 1..N to select the hypercube face direction. `d=randi(N)`
- To select a specific face among the two possible ones, draw a random integer called s which can take either of the two values: 0 or 1. `s =randi(2)-1`
- Draw a random uniformly distributed vector called v of length N in the range 0..1. `v=rand(N,1)`
- replace s as the d-th coordinate in v and multiply the result by the edge length E. `v(d)=s`, `v=E*v`

Plotting 1000 points on the surface or the 3-d cube of edge-length 2 would we something like:

```
N=3;  
E=2;
Nsamples=1000; 
d=randi(N,1,Nsamples);  
s =randi(2,1,Nsamples)-1;  
v=rand(N,Nsamples);  
for i=1:Nsamples  
  v(d(i),i)=s(i);  
end 
v = E*v;
plot3(v(1,:),v(2,:),v(3,:),'.');
```

This implementation is probably not the best in terms of pure efficiency, but you understand how it works.

Hope this helps.

Adrien.

Comment: Hi Adrien, Thank you for the reply. I have one question though. So, for example, when you s (the face of the cube, it will give either 0 and 1). In cases, where s is zero, when we multiply by the random numbers, then the number itself will be zero. Is there a workaround for this? Thank You

Comment: @Sam: I do not multiply by `s`. The variable `s` is used to set one of the coordinates to 0 or 1 in order to put the point on one of the two faces of the (hyper-)cube that has a normal vector oriented along the d^th coordinate. also the cube is not centered the origin is one of its vertices and all its points have positive coordinates.-